# Help parsing my own expression tree, C#

Tags: c#, parsing, expression-trees

I have the following code. I constructed an expression tree and I am stuck parsing it to find the result

You will find the details within my code

```
public enum OpertaionType { add, sub, div, mul} 

public class Node {
    public Node(Node lhs, Node rhs, OpertaionType opType, int index) {
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
        this.opType = opType;
        this.index = index;
    }
    Node lhs;
    Node rhs;
    OpertaionType opType;
    int index;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I don't want this to be part of the node data structure
        // because in the actual implementation I will end up referencing an
        // array of data

        int[] value = new int[5];

        Node[] nodes = new Node[value.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            value[i] = i+1;
            nodes[i] = new Node(null, null, 0, i);
        }



        // suppose I constructed the tree like that 
        // note that the end nodes are marked by non-negative index that indexes the
        // values array

        Node a = new Node(nodes[0], nodes[1], OpertaionType.add, -1);
        Node b = new Node(nodes[2], a, OpertaionType.mul, -1);
        Node c = new Node(b, nodes[3], OpertaionType.div, -1);

        // How can I find the result of Node c programatically
        // such that the result is (a[2]*(a[0]+a[1]))/a[3] = 9/4

    }
}
```

Comment: heyy hold on .. you may share your amazing knowledge here !!

Comment: ...Expression Trees as homework hah? I highly doubt any school have had their syllabus updated to teaching Expression Trees :/

Comment: @Dreas: I teach expression trees in the first semester, hence my question.

Comment: really ?  Quite an interesting curriculum you've got there.  ...wish my teachers where as up to date as you are heh

Comment: @ Will .. I wanna serialize the expression tree through WCF service !! it's not serializable mr. genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple elementary intro to C# 3.0's own expression trees, see e.g. [here](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/c-30-language-enhancements-for-linq-part-3-expression-trees/); unfortunately I am not aware of a really broad and deep text on the subject (maybe a book..?).

As for your own hand-rolled format, you can evaluate it most simply by recursion; in pseudocode:

```
def valof(node):
  if node.index >= 0: 
    return whateverarray[node.index]
  L = valof(node.lhs)
  R = valof(node.rhs)
  if node.opType == add:
    return L + R
  if node.opType == mul:
    return L * R
  # etc etc
```

As a further twist, as you appear to want fraction results while the input values are integers, remember to use a fraction / rational number type for your computations - not sure if C# comes with one, but worst case you can find plenty on the net;-).

Comment: the built-in expression tree is not serializable... I wanna pass it through a WCF service :) I have no idea whether this is acheivable

Answer (score 3):

You need a recursive algorithm, passing the values array (code untested):

```
class Node{
  //...
  double compute(int[] values){
    if(index >= 0)
      return values[index]; // leaf node; value stored in array
    switch(opType){
      case add: return lhs.compute(values)+rhs.compute(values);
      case sub: return lhs.compute(values)-rhs.compute(values);
      case div: return lhs.compute(values)*rhs.compute(values);
      case mul: return lhs.compute(values)/rhs.compute(values);
    }
    throw new Exception("unsupported operation type");
  }
}
```

Notice that this performs all computations in double; if you really want 9/4, you would need to use a rational type.